# SQL joining columns that have different content

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My code:

```
$newResult = $conn -> query("SELECT wp_nf3_fields.id, wp_nf3_fields.parent_id, wp_postmeta.meta_key
FROM wp_postmeta
LEFT JOIN wp_nf3_fields ON wp_postmeta.meta_key = wp_nf3_fields.id
");
```

I'm writing a PHP file that is trying to join two database tables based on the entries in their columns. The problem is that the entries in the column wp_postmeta.meta_key are like this

```
_field_1
_field_2
```

while the column wp_nf3_fields.id entries are like this

```
1
2
```

How can I match these two? Is there a way of just cutting off the *field* bit from the first column so that I can compare them? I'm ok with PHP but really not very familiar with SQL so would appreciate any advice!

Comment: use right(wp_postmeta.meta_key,1)

Comment: @DanielMarcus What if the number consists of more than one digit? It's better to do a substring and remove the `_field_` part or like Gordon's approach, just add the `_field_` part to the digit only fields.

Comment: Good point - see updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use string concatenation:

```
FROM wp_postmeta LEFT JOIN
     wp_nf3_fields
     ON wp_postmeta.meta_key = CONCAT('_field_', wp_nf3_fields.id);
```

Comment: The issue of having more than 9 IDs didn't even occur to me. This works great thank you!

Answer (score 1):

...or the other way around:

```
FROM wp_postmeta LEFT JOIN
     wp_nf3_fields
     ON right(wp_postmeta.meta_key,charindex('_', reverse(wp_postmeta.meta_key))-1) =  wp_nf3_fields.id
```

Comment: Oh true - so use charindex of the second _ to define the proper 'right' position in that case

Comment: The concatenation method in Gordon's answer is simpler, and can also take advantage of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

if you string is alway equal to  *field*  you could use replace so you could manage also number with more then a digit

```
  ("SELECT wp_nf3_fields.id
      , wp_nf3_fields.parent_id
      , wp_postmeta.meta_key
  FROM wp_postmeta
  LEFT JOIN wp_nf3_fields 
     ON wwp_nf3_fields.id =  replace(wp_postmeta.meta_key, '_field_', '')
  ");
```